# How to rename Http directory 'Controller' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am thinking of renaming app/Http directory name to my custom name. Like rename "Http to MyCustomName".

**Default Laravel folder:**
app/Http/Controllers

**After renaming:**
app/MyName/Controllers

Can we do that in Laravel?
If yes, then where should I change the namespace and all?

Comment: What's your main reason for wanting to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `$namespace` inside the `Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` so you could stay mention the controller in your routes using the relative format.

Then execute the command :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Ok please explain more what you mean by _it won't work._

Comment: @webdev Did you change the namespaces in all the classes in that directory and then run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Forgot to fire command composer dump-autoload.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. And you must change namespaces of the all classes which exists in `Http` folder. And change `$namespace` property in the `RouteServiceProvider`.

But this is not a good idea, because `Http` directory is [one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure#the-http-directory) of the basic directories of Laravel.